# Find out which iPhone version

Tags: iphone, ios, uidevice

My app uses the camera and face recognition extensively and I recently found out that it's slow on the iPhone 4.

I know you can find the ios version and what type of device it is.

Is there a way to find out programmatically which iPhone is being used (4/4S/5)?

Comment: What did you tried? There is plenty of answers for this questions...
A solution: https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/blob/master/UIDevice-Hardware.m

Answer (score 1):

iOS Version: `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]`

Device Model: [How to programmatically differentiate between iphone 4 and iphone 4S?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292246/how-to-programmatically-differentiate-between-iphone-4-and-iphone-4s/8304788#8304788) or [How do I detect which iOS device my user is using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224508/how-do-i-detect-which-ios-device-my-user-is-using)